# ReWrite rule for IIS 7+

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, url-rewriting

I have a site that generates the following url structure that I would like to rewrite.

current url

```
domain.com/Store/catid/20/prodId/50/pair-of-socks.aspx
```

desired url

```
domain.com/pair-of-socks.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how many edge cases you need to cater for. A simple solution would be:

Match URL (\w+/)+(\w+.\w{3,4})
Rewrite URL {R:2}

Comment: Thanks lat3ncy! I'll give this a try and see what happens.